# Updated Google Maps Store locator as Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Does Anyone know of a site that has converted the google maps api store locator to a jquery version?

Comment: please elaborate, im not sure what you mean

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html they use javascript not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any jQuery maps plugin..

I like goMap,
http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/